# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes at Logo on startup

Tags: system-installation, startup, debian, logo

I have a Dell Inspiron with NVIDIA Geforce GTX. I have just install a brand new Ubuntu 16.04 but the system freezes at the logo on startup. I tried to use the Boot repair but still didnt fix it. Follow the URL generated by the Boot Repair. Someone could help me?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16073684/